# How to download Firestore scheduled backups?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

There is a new feature on firestore that lets you create scheduled backups.

I was able to create a backup following this instructions:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/backups#create_and_manage_backup_schedules

I'm trying to figure out how to download the backup files to my local computer. Are this files stored on a bucket?

Are this files accesible in a different way?

Thanks in advance, I could not find anything on the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't download them.  You run additional commands to [list them](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/backups#list_backup_schedules) (they are stored by GCP so you don't have to), then [restore the one you want](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/backups#restore_data_from_a_database_backup).

If you want something to download, then [create an export](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import) and find the files in a bucket.  But you should know that an export is not the same thing as a point-in-time backup.